# How to display pdf on canvas using angular7 and fabric js

Tags: angular7

I want to display a pdf as an image on canvas using angular7 and fabric js

i am not able to find any code to try in angular7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to solve this...i have used pdfjsLib  and i have imported in my ts file (import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';)

```
 public src="/assets/myPhotos.pdf";
 showPdf(){
pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.src).then(doc =>{

 // console.log("this file has "+ doc._pdfInfo.numPages+ "pages");
  doc.getPage(1).then(page => {
    var myCanvas =  <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("my_canvas");
    var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    myCanvas.width = viewport.width;
    myCanvas.height = viewport.height;

    page.render({
      canvasContext : context,
      viewport : viewport
    })
  })
});
```

}